# Reg Ex Django Url Conf

Tags: regex, django, urlconf

These is my django URLconf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^hello/$', hello),
    (r'^polls/$', 'mysite.polls.views.index'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'mysite.polls.views.detail'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'mysite.polls.views.results'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'mysite.polls.views.vote'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I don't understand what the r in this regex does:

```
r'^polls/$
```

I don't understand what this Regex does:

```
(?P<poll_id>\d+)
```

And I don't understand why in:

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

There is no `$` sign and it still works...

I don't understand what URLconf I have to add, to see a site under `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'r' denotes a 'raw' string, which makes life easier when trying to write regexes (you don't end up escaping the escape characters). http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#raw-string-notation

As far as the second question goes, it creates a named match group of 1 or more digits, and passes that value to the view as 'poll_id'. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

The reason there isn't a $ on the admin string is that you want all urls that start with /admin to be passed to the admin app. $ is a special character that defines the end of a string. So if there were an $, then only the url /admin would be passed to the admin app, not /admin/foo or /admin/foo/bar.

Comment: Looks like the 1.2 version of the docs are gone. Here's the link to the current docs as of today: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Answer (score 1):

read the docs, http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-urls

Answer (score 1):

My python regex is rusty but here goes:

```
r'^polls/$
```

the `^` means starts with.
The `$` means the end

`(?P<poll_id>\d+)` means an integer `\d+` which in my code will be put into a variable `poll_id`

`(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`
doesn't have a $ because you may not want the url to end there. You want admin/somethingelse to be passed to your admin.sites.urls class.

Answer (score 0):

The `r` means the provided string is raw and escape characters should be ignored.  The `(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))` line has no `$` because it is an include for another url confs.  So the end `$` is somewhere in the `admin.site.urls`.